# How to alter Jettison JSON format to exclude outer object wrapper?

Tags: java, json, gson, jettison

I just started working in an environment (`Java`) that uses Jettison exclusively for marshalling (`Object`->`JSON`) and GSON for the unmarshalling (`JSON`->`Object`).

I have been having problems unmarshalling JSON objects that were created with the Jettison marshaller. I've noticed that for an object of class X, the jettison produced string is

```
{"X":{"prop1":"value1", "prop2":"value2"}}
```

When I try to un-marshal it with GSON, both prop1 and prop2 have null values.

Not trusting the format of the JSON string Jettison produced, I tried to deserialize the string

```
{"prop1":"value1", "prop2":"value2"}
```

without the outer JSON wrapper, and GSON treated it correctly.

Is there a way to get Jettison to produce JSON without the outer wrapper attached?  Or some way to get Jettison and GSON to work together?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Jettison, but I think it's possible to handle this with GSON.

First of all, we can use GSON's [`JsonParser`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) to read the JSON into a tree of elements:

```
String json = "{\"X\":{\"prop1\":\"value1\", \"prop2\":\"value2\"}}";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(json);
JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

Now we want to extract the value of the "X" property of this object. If we know the name of the property, we can just use:

```
JsonElement value = object.get("X");
```

However, from the question it seemed like the name of this property can vary. In this case, we need to dynamically get the first property, for example like this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = object.entrySet();
Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> firstEntry = entrySet.iterator().next();
JsonElement value = firstEntry.getValue();
```

Once we have this value, we can deserialize it to an instance of our class as usual:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
X x = gson.fromJson(value, X.class);
System.out.println(x.prop1);  // prints value1
System.out.println(x.prop2);  // prints value2
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion utiliizing GSON.  This will most likely be the path we may end up taking if Jettison does not offer any ways to modify the json.

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem? I am running into the same and was wondering if you can help me.